# Controle do aparecimento de modal

Tags: php, javascript, session, modal

Eu criei um modal, que ao clicar em um clique ele pergunta se a pessoa deseja cadastrar o e-mail para receber mais informações. E este modal esta em mais de um link ao longo do site.
Teria como eu controlar o aparecimento do mesmo?
Tipo se a pessoa já viu este modal, mesmo que não tenha colocado o e-mail (para não ficar chato), ele so apareça uma vez?

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: você quer que apareça uma vez por visita ou uma única vez ao acessar o site? para ambos vc pode criar sessões na maquina do cliente, ou cookies.

Comment: quero fazer por visita!

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

***Janela Modal***

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        <?php if(!$_SESSION['modal_aberta']){ ?>
        $("#myModal").show(); // se ainda não tiver aberto a modal, exibe
        <?php
            $_SESSION['modal_aberta'] = '1'; // seta que já foi aberta a modal.
        ?>
        <?php } ?>
    });
</script>
```

Não esqueça que no seu arquivo principal, deverá conter o session_start() para iniciar a session.

Comment: Esses dia fiz uma pergunta sobre o atributo `aria` e li li e não entendi, pode dar alguma dica o que exatamente ele faz em seu código ?

Comment: As tags ARIA servem para explicar melhor a semântica do seu HTML para tecnologias de acessibilidade, como por exemplo leitores de tela que varrem um web app e transformam essas informações em uma descrição amigável para pessoas com deficiência visual.

De uma olhada nessa resposta: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474099/what-is-html5-aria

Comment: Bom dia! tentei fazer, mas aqui no meu ainda mostra a modal. Iniciei a sessão mas não deu certo não.

Comment: Poste seu código, como tentou fazer.

Comment: Segue o codigo abaixo.

Answer (score 0):

Bom eu iniciei a sessão e setei a variavel para 0.

```
<?php session_start(); 
$_SESSION['modal_aberta'] = 0; ?>
```

Depois peguei o codigo do JQuery e fiz assim

```
  <script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    <?php if(!$_SESSION['modal_aberta'] == 0){ ?>
    $("#myModal3").show(); // se ainda não tiver aberto a modal, exibe
    <?php
        $_SESSION['modal_aberta'] = 1; // seta que já foi aberta a modal.
    }else{ ?>
      $("#myModal3").hide();
    <?php } ?>
}); </script>
```